# Use Spark to list all files in a Hadoop HDFS directory?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hadoop

I want to loop through all text files in a Hadoop dir and count all the occurrences of the word "error". Is there a way to do a `hadoop fs -ls /users/ubuntu/` to list all the files in a dir with the Apache Spark Scala API?

From the given [first example](https://spark.apache.org/examples.html), the spark context seems to only access files individually through something like:

```
val file = spark.textFile("hdfs://target_load_file.txt")
```

In my problem, I do not know how many nor the names of the files in the HDFS folder beforehand. Looked at the [spark context docs](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/core/index.html#org.apache.spark.SparkContext) but couldn't find this kind of functionality.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use a wildcard:

```
val errorCount = sc.textFile("hdfs://some-directory/*")
                   .flatMap(_.split(" ")).filter(_ == "error").count
```

Comment: What if I wanted to report the name of the file where the error has occurred?

Comment: Use `sc.wholeTextFiles`. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29521665/how-to-map-filenames-to-rdd-using-sc-textfiles3n-bucket-csv for pretty much that question.

Answer (score 6):

```
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.{FileSystem, FileUtil, Path}
import scala.collection.mutable.Stack


val fs = FileSystem.get( sc.hadoopConfiguration )
var dirs = Stack[String]()
val files = scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer.empty[String]
val fs = FileSystem.get(sc.hadoopConfiguration)

dirs.push("/user/username/")

while(!dirs.isEmpty){
    val status = fs.listStatus(new Path(dirs.pop()))
    status.foreach(x=> if(x.isDirectory) dirs.push(x.getPath.toString) else 
    files+= x.getPath.toString)
}
files.foreach(println)
```

Comment: This is the most rigorously correct answer to the question as stated in the title. The accepted answer gives OP a more specific answer to what the question itself asks for, but anyone coming from google will likely be looking for this.

Answer (score 2):

For a local installation, (the hdfs default path `fs.defaultFS` can be found by reading `/etc/hadoop/core.xml`):

For instance,

```
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.{FileSystem, Path}

val conf = sc.hadoopConfiguration
conf.set("fs.defaultFS", "hdfs://localhost:9000")
val hdfs: org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem = org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(conf)
 
val fileStatus = hdfs.listStatus(new Path("hdfs://localhost:9000/foldername/"))
val fileList = fileStatus.map(x => x.getPath.toString)
fileList.foreach(println)
```